# How can I make Discord bots display the "Bot is typing ..." status?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So if I have a long command like this:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def longCommand(ctx):
   #typing status
   sleep(10)
   bot.say("Done!")
```

Didn't find anything in the documentation or here, unfortunately.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

EDIT: Newer versions of discord require you to use the new syntax:

```
@bot.command()
async def mycommand(ctx):
    async with ctx.typing():
        # do expensive stuff here
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
    await ctx.send('done!')
```

Older versios used this:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def longCommand(ctx):
   await bot.send_typing(ctx.channel)
   await asyncio.sleep(10)
   await bot.say("Done!")
```

Remember to use `await` on every asynchronous call to coroutines.

Answer (score 9):

If you use the rewrite branch, then all `Messageable`s have a [`typing`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable.typing) context manager that allows you to type indefinitely, and a [`trigger_typing`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable.trigger_typing) coroutine that displays the typing message for a few seconds.

```
@bot.command()
async def longCommand(ctx):
   async with ctx.typing():
        await sleep(10)
   await ctx.send("Done!")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@bot.command()
async def type(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.trigger_typing()
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await ctx.send("Done!")
```

This worked for me!
Im using Discord.py (not rewrite)