# Discord.py bot does not type

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am trying to make my discord bot trigger typing for 2 seconds. This code does not work because the bot does not say it is typing when the function is running. It will wait for 10 seconds and then send the message correctly but it will not show it is typing in the channel

```
async with channel.typing():
    print("waiting for: ", typetime)
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    print("wait complete")
    await channel.send(random.choice(messages))
```

Comment: That's because it's never typing, you just send a message

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make Discord bots display the "Bot is typing ..." status?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51252714/how-can-i-make-discord-bots-display-the-bot-is-typing-status)

Comment: Its answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51252714/how-can-i-make-discord-bots-display-the-bot-is-typing-status?noredirect=1&lq=1